# Inserting symbol with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, symbols

I would like to insert a symbol with VBA. The following works well:

```
Sub testver()    
Sheets("mapping").Cells(1, 10) = ChrW(&H634)
end sub
```

.. but now I would like to make the character code variable. It gets the number from a mapping  table. I simplified the code and excluded the mapping part as that is not important for my question. But I get an error if I use 'codec' in the ChrW part. Codec should be 634. Anyone knows how to write this part of the vba code correctly?

```
Sub testver2()
codec = Sheets("mapping").Cells(11, 1)
Sheets("mapping").Cells(1, 10) = ChrW(&H"codec")
end sub
```

Thanks in advance! 
Amir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Sub testver2()
    codec = Sheets("mapping").Cells(11, 1)
    Sheets("mapping").Cells(1, 10) = ChrW("&H" & codec)
End Sub
```